# HSQLDB 2.2.9: understanding server.properties file

Tags: hsqldb

I am running hsqlddb 2.2.9 on ubuntu Linux but I am struggling to understand the server.properties file. With hsqldb installed under /usr/local, when I start the server with java org.hsqldb.server.Server from the place I put the server.properties file, suppose server.properties is:

```
server.database.0=file:/usr/local/hsqldb-2.2.9/hsqldb/hibernate/hiberdb
server.dbname.0=hiberdb
```

Then I get a subdirectory hibdernate with everthing in it labeled

```
hibderdb.{log,script,properties,tmp}
```

with hibderdb.tmp an empty directory. So far so good.

---

However I cannot understand hyper sql db's logic in the following cases:

Suppose server.properties is:

```
server.database.0=file:/usr/local/hsqldb-2.2.9/hsqldb/hibernate
server.dbname.0=hiberdb
```

then the hibderdb alias is ignode and I get files

```
hibernate.{log,properties,script,tmp}
```

in the same directory as the server.properties file (i.e. in the current directory).

or even the following:

```
server.database.0=file:/usr/local/hsqldb-2.2.9/hsqldb/hibernate/
server.dbname.0=hiberdb
```

then all I get is a hibernate subdirectory with no hibderdb.* files and instead I have files

```
hibernate/{.log,.properties,.script,.tmp}
```

(these are hidden Unix files, and again the alias property dbname is ignored).

The HSQLDB documentation has an example:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_server_props

```
server.database.1=file:/opt/db/mydb
server.dbname.1=enrolments
```

Is this example outdated or wrong?

Thanks,

Jason Posit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `server.dbname.0=hiberdb` is totally unrelated to the other line in the properties file.

This 'alias' is used when accessing the server from a client.

The example in the documentation is correct. The external database client is dealing with a database alias it knows as 'enrolments', and does not need to know where you store the files on your server.

Access to your 'hiberdb' client is always via the URL such as `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/hiberdb` no matter where you put the files.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was helpful.